# sqlite change date format of every cell in column

Tags: sql, sqlite, date-format, date-formatting

I have a table with a large number of rows. 
One column contains dates in the format 
'%m/%d/%Y'
and I want to change all of them to format
'%Y-%m-%d'

the usual:
update table
set mydate = '6'

doesn't work I guess because the date is always changing. How would I do that in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the fields in the date string are properly padded with zeros, you can [extract them as substrings](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyDate = substr(MyDate, 7, 4) || '-' ||
             substr(MyDate, 1, 2) || '-' ||
             substr(MyDate, 4, 2)
```

Comment: that looks like it could do the trick but I end up with "9-07-20-8-" from "19/07/2018"
If you explain how the || - || works here I am sure I can modify it to work. what does substr(MyDate, 7, 4) do for example? Give me the characters between 4th and 7th character?

Comment: thanks. this one worked:
select substr('19/07/2018', 1, 2)
|| '-' ||
substr('19/07/2018', 4, 2)
|| '-' ||
substr('19/07/2018', 7, 4)

Comment: `||` just concatenates strings. You get garbage when you try to execute this statement multiple times.