# Incrementing date column in sqlite3

Tags: datetime, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 table with dates stored as `text not null` with the format **MM-DD-YY**, and have been doing most of my manipulation in Java by iterating through the cursor, however, it's proving to be a bit ugly/cumbersome, and **I was wondering if there's any way to do an update statement in sqlite3 to increment/decrement all records by a certain number of days**. I'm mostly having trouble figuring out how to convert my text column into a format that I can use with something along the lines of  `datetime(myDate, '+1 Day');`. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of the built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) documents the supported date format:

> YYYY-MM-DD

You should store your date values in this format.
If you cannot do this, you can [use substr() to extract the fields of the date and convert it into the supported format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125390/sqlite-change-date-format-of-every-cell-in-column).

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: Although not quite what I was looking for, this helped me work towards a workaround, thank you!